# Как можно хранить данные в браузере так, что бы очистка кэша их не удаляла?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, браузер

Мне нужно каким-то образом идентифицировать пользователя / браузер, если пользователь очистил кэш. Это как-то можно сделать?

Comment: Сделайте 2 запроса в гугль `неубиваемые куки` и `суперкуки`. P.S. Это разные способы идентификации.

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что никак, а если как-то и можно, то это исправят. Вы хотите нарушить privacy пользователя, это недружественное по отношению к пользователю поведение. Просто не делайте так.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать localStorage в браузере
P.S. не могу комментом ответить из-за нехватки "кармы". Ответ не претендует на полноту решения.